# Looking for local beers on the Canary Islands?

Tags: breweries, local

The common beers in Gran Canaria are [Topical and Dorada](http://www.sabmiller.com/index.asp?pageid=1012).

- What other local beers are there on the Canary Island?
- Is there any microbrewery / local brewery in the Canary Island?
- Are there craft beers in the Las Palma de Gran Canaria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craft beer and beer tourism seems to have not yet hit the Canary Islands.

The other notable beer local to the Canary Islands that we know of is Viva (http://www.cervezaviva.com/).

We don't know of any craft beers in Las Palmas de Gran Canaria but Cerveza Gourmet (http://www.ratebeer.com/p/cerveza-gourmet-las-palmas-de-gran-canaria/34492/) 
appears to be a store to visit if you are looking for a wide selection to choose from.

Answered by: The Gastrograph Team